Why is there a disparity b/w array of chars and string in C?
I noticed that if you define a string in C you need to take into consideration the nul terminator, which made intuitive sense that the computer need someway to check that the string has hit its end.
But then when you do something like anytype arr[] = {val1, val2, ...}, you suddenly don't need to take into consideration the nul terminator.
How does the computer know that it has hit the end of the array without any special identifier.
i tried searching but the answers were not specific to how does the computer know the end of an array.

How does the computer know that it has hit the end of the array without any special identifier -- In C, there is no check to see if you go beyond the bounds an array.  You are responsible for checking bounds.

It doesn't.  You either provide a sentinel value, like the null terminator for a c-strings, or you pass the size with the array

If you have an array, compiler knows how many elements there are. If your array decays to pointer (e.g. when you pass an array to another function), nobody knows its size unless you pass explicitly as another argument or you use a special value to mark the end.

The "computer" doesn't know. The compiler (sometimes) does and the programmer, and they make this check in either compile time or explicitly in the code. The difference between arbitrary data and strings is that strings are supposed to have values in a very specific subset range of char values, allowing it to have special sentinel value which is still within the char range. Other, general array types do not have this luxury.

The main difference between strings and other arrays is, that there are functions dealing with strings that expect the 0 byte as terminator. For all other arrays (that could also be char arrays without terminator) no such functions exist. Also: Expect for strings, how would you select such a terminator value? Generally, all values can be used within the array and therefore cannot be used to indicate the end.

this char one[100] = "one"; is a valid string with length 3. It can grow in place to a string of length 99. OTOH char two[] = "two"; is a string of length 3 that cannot grow in place... and char *ptr = "ptr"; currently points to a read only array with 4 elements; but can be made to point to any other array (or part of it) -- it is a string if the array (or part of it) it points to contains a 0. Conversely char three[3] = "333"; IS NOT a string (no '\0' terminator) but it is nevertheless a valid array.

Plain freestanding C does not even know about strings (except maybe if you consider string literals). Strings are only a thing if you #include <string.h> (or a few other headers) and use string functions from there. Strings are a Standard Library convention (used in many many other libraries and applications with the same meaning). If you want to you can write string stuff using a different convention and NOT USING strcmp(), strcpy(), printf("%s", ...), etc etc. The conventional Standard Library definition for string prevents using strings with embedded NULs.

For an array arr with a complete array type (i.e. an array whose length has been declared or whose length has been auto-sized from its initializer) its length is given by (sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]). This does not work for arrays declared as parameters of functions, because those are not really arrays, they are "adjusted" to become pointers.

The int main(int argc, char *argv[]) does both. It provides the number of elements in argc and also provides a sentinel value (not included by argc) in the argv array. The element argv[argc] == NULL.

Unlike other languages, in C, arrays don't include their inherent sizes. Without any checks, it's entirely possible to read or write outside of an array bounds. In modern systems, there can be some protection provided by segmentation and paged virtual memory, but it will still let you read outside of the array within the memory owned by the process.
To answer your question:
The \0 character automatically added to the end of strings is a standard terminator used by many C functions. It's so important that the UTF-8 standard was designed to be compatible with it by explicitly forbidding overlong encodings.
However, there is no standard terminator for the ends of other types of arrays like integers, floating point, structures, etc. In these cases, you have to provide the size of the array so that the called function won't access out of bounds.
In some cases, you may know that certain values cannot exist, so for example, you could use -1 to indicate the end of an array of integers. Any design decisions here would be specific to the application.

There are a couple of misconceptions going on in other answers.
In C, an array is a special object. An array in C has:

an element type
a length

For example, int xs[7]; declares an array of element type int and length 7 elements.
⟶ This is information the compiler keeps about your array.

The problem is that you cannot pass arrays around like you can other objects. In order to reference an array, you must use a pointer. You see this most commonly when trying to pass an array as argument to a function. You cannot pass the array, but you can pass a pointer to it:
#include <stdio.h>

int sum( int * xs, int n )
{
  int total = 0;
  while (--n) total += xs[n];
  return total;
}

int main( void )
{
  int primes[7] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 };
  printf( "%d\n", sum( primes, 7 ) );
  return 0;
}

We see that the function does not get the array itself, but a pointer to the (first element of the) array. Since pointers do not have an associated number of elements, we must also pass that information to the function to know when the array ends.

The trick here is that the array name “decays” to a pointer to the first element. This behavior is part of the C language. You could easily write &(primes[0]) instead, but that is the long way around when just writing primes is the same thing. This is called “array-to-pointer decay”.

The next trick is that the [] array subscript operator is syntactic sugar for a pointer offset lookup:
  xs  [2] = 42;  // A
*(xs + 2) = 42;  // B

In this example, lines A and B are exactly the same thing! In fact, line A is rewritten by the compiler as line B behind the scenes.
⟶ That is why it is possible to write the array indexing weirdly as: 2[xs] = 42; — it is the same as *(2 + xs) = 42!

We can get the compiler to tell us the number of elements in an array using a trick: (size in bytes of the array) divided by (size in bytes of a single element). This is expressed in code as:
sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0])

We can use, through it is often most convenient via a macro:
#define ARRAY_SIZE(array) (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))
...
printf( "%d\n", sum( primes, ARRAY_SIZE(primes) ) );


We often use fewer elements in an array than available. We then need to track both the number of elements used and the total number of elements available. Again, in C, the compiler knows the total number of elements available — until you pass a pointer to the array somewhere.
We do this when doing things like adding to an array:
#define MAX_XS 100
int xs[MAX_XS];
int n_xs = 0;

// Add an x to xs
if (n_xs < MAX_XS)
{
  xs[n_xs++] = x;
}


All right, what does any of this have to do with strings?

A string in C is an array! But it has an additional characteristic: the string data itself is terminated with a “nul character” (a zero, or '\0'). This makes it easy to pass strings around without also having to pass around either their length or their capacity.
In other words, I can write:
char s[100];
strcpy( s, "Hello " );
strcat( s, username );
strcat( s, "!" );

As long as username is fewer than (100TOTAL - 6strlen("Hello ") - 1strlen("!") - 1NUL) characters long, everything will fit. But I don’t have to mess with ARRAY_SIZE() or s_length or anything like that.

Sentinel characters appear in other contexts as well. For example, the second argument to main() is an array of pointers to strings. The array itself is terminated with a NULL pointer!
In other words:
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
  assert( argv[argc] == NULL );

Using special characters is not always a very good idea though. In fact, strings in C cannot contain nul characters for this very reason: it is impossible to embed a nul in a C string, simply because the nul indicates the end of the string!

tl;dr

The compiler knows the length of an array.
A pointer indexes an unknown number of elements — it can be indexed like an array but it is not.
Arrays do not need to be terminated with a sentinel value.
C strings are terminated by the sentinel nul character for convenience.
A C string is data stored in a (potentially larger) array.



How does the computer know that it has hit the end of the array without any special identifier.

It doesn't. Arrays in C don't store any runtime metadata regarding their length, type, or anything else (this is true of all types in C).  An array is just a sequence of objects of a given type.
Under most circumstances array expressions decay to pointers to their first element; when you pass an array expression as an argument to a function:
int arr[10] = { ... };
foo( arr ); // == &arr[0]
...

all the function receives is a pointer:
void foo( int *a )
{
  ...
}

A pointer points to a single object of the given type; you cannot know from that pointer value alone whether that object is part of an array or how many elements follow it.
You must either pass the number of elements as a separate parameter or use a sentinel value to mark the end of the data (which may not be the last element of the array).  This is why you have to use the 0 terminator for strings, because that's the only way the various str* routines know where the end of the string is.  0 works because it doesn't correspond to a printable value or control character; it's an "out of band" value for that particular use case.
However, under other circumstances, a 0-valued byte may be valid data and can't be used as a sentinel (hence all strings are arrays of character type, but not all arrays of character type are strings).  In that case you'd have to store the size in a separate variable.

Arrays in C don't store any runtime metadata regarding their length, type, or anything else Not really.  sizeof(type) will give you the sized of the object and for an array it will be the size of the array element multiplied by the number of elements in the array.  Its only once the array decays into a pointer does the size information disappear.

@NathanOliver: Except for VLAs, sizeof is a compile-time operation, not runtime.  The compiler keeps track of that data during translation; it's not stored with the array at runtime.
